# Strange result using long double in C++

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, precision

Using long double arithmetic in C++, the number **50,000,056,019,485.52605438232421875** squared yields **2,500,005,601,951,690,788,240,883,712**. Meanwhile, the number **50,000,056,019,485.526050567626953125** (which differs from the first number by less than 0.001) squared yields **2,500,005,601,951,690,787,704,012,800**, which differs from the first square by almost 1 billion. With the differences highlighted:

50,000,056,019,485.52605**4382324218750** ^ 2 = 2,500,005,601,951,690,78**8,240,883,712**
50,000,056,019,485.52605**0567626953125** ^ 2 = 2,500,005,601,951,690,78**7,704,012,800**

Long double's range in my machine goes from ~1e-300 to ~1e+300. I fully understand the inability to represent all the numbers in the range, but I didn't expect such a big difference. Could anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: You've got about 18 significant digits of accuracy in all cases.  That's exactly what you ought to expect from floating point arithmetic.  You have to look at *relative* error rather than *absolute*.

Comment: Floating point is hard: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e46d6bc4009361a6

Comment: I find the best way to understand doubles is to assume that literally every operation will randomly add or remove ~0.001% (including storing it in a variable). With this assumption in mind, you'll end up writing much better code.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit more on why only 18 significant digits for long doubles?

Comment: If you have an x86 machine, `long double` has a 64-bit fractional part, so at best, every number can be expected to be correct to within about 1 part in 2^64.  2^64 is about 10^19.  So 18 or 19 digits is about right.

Comment: Floating point types basically store values in scientific notation. They only store a limited number of decimals, usually too few to fully represent the desired result. A lot of rounding occurs.

Comment: The computed squares differ by .54 billion, not “almost 1 billion,” and the mathematical squares would differ by .38 billion. Let x be the first number, which is about 5•10^13. The second number is x − 3.814697265625•10^−6. Squaring that produces x^2 − 2•3.814697265625•10^−6•x + (3.814697265625•10^−6)^2, which differs from x^2 by about 7.6•10^−6•x, which is about 7.6•10^−6 • 5•10^13 = 38•10^7, or about .38 billion. So the rounding error in this calculation is about .16 billion out of 25•10^26 = .16•10^9 / (25•10^26) = 6.4•10^-20, less than 1 part in 2^63.

Answer (score 1):

**Math**

Given `d` as a small value compared to `a`

The *expected* difference of `(a+d)*(a+d) - (a)*(a)` is about `2*a*d`.

Here `a` is about 50,000,056,000,000.0, `d` is about 0.00000381... and `2*a*d` is about 381,000,000.0.  That is within a factor of two of the difference seen using `long double`: 536,870,912.0.

"I didn't expect such a big difference." is only "off" less than a factor of 2.  Given the squares represent rounded products, the difference of the squares  seen here is **reasonable**.

---

Some details:

**`long double`**

Given the following and `long double` as 10-byte, `a` and `b` are consecutive `long double` values.  They differ by 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) or about 1 part in 2<sup>64</sup>.  Both decimal code constants are exactly saved as  `a, b`.

```
long double b = 50000056019485.526054382324218750L; // 0x1.6bcc5c9f50ec355cp+45
long double a = 50000056019485.526050567626953125L; // 0x1.6bcc5c9f50ec355ap+45
// difference
long double d =              0.000003814697265625L; // 0x0.0000000000000002p+45
```

The square of `a, b` are not execrably representable as `long double`. Instead the reported squares are the *rounded* values.  They differ by 2 ULP.

```
long double bb = 2500005601951690788240883712.0L; // 0x1.027e98e7c774ede8cp+91
long double aa = 2500005601951690787704012800.0L; // 0x1.027e98e7c774ede88p+91
// difference                       536870912.0 .... 0x0.00000000000000004p+91
```

When multiplying 2 floating point numbers, the error in the product is expected to be within +/-0.5 ULP.  Here the ULP is 5,368,70,912 and indeed the squares are correct to within 0.5*